# Minor Refactoring in Java Swing application causes huge slowdown

Tags: java, swing

I've been tasked with doing refactoring to a Java Swing application we have here that's pretty crufty. My job is to clean up the code and make it more dynamic as we're going to start using it with a second project and it needs to be able to adjust appropriately.  There is a small portion of one window that contains

- A button
- A JFormattedTextField that is used to select dates.
- A 3X4 table of JLabels that display data.

The person who originally wrote this simply used a GridBagLayout JPanel and then hardcoded everything, including the table's header and row label's and left empty JLabel's in the dynamic data position.  When the dynamic information is received `setText` is called with the text data.  Part of my refactoring will cause the entire table to be dynamic in dimension as well as content so I decided to make the table a sub-panel with a GridLayout and dynamically set the contents and dimensions with this piece of code:

```
    public void updateInfoPanel(ArrayList rows) {
        System.out.println("Updating Info Panel!");
        //genericInfo is the new sub panel in question.
        genericInfo.removeAll();
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.setColumns(rows.get(0).length);
        layout.setRows(rows.size());
        genericInfo.setLayout(layout);
        for(String[] row : rows) {
            for(String element : row) {
                genericInfo.add(new Label(element));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have verified that this is only ever getting called one time per window creation but the entire window is now incredibly sluggish.  It can take >5 seconds to respond to clicks in other parts of the frame that used to respond in fractions of a second.  Does anyone know what would cause this?  Is there something about GridLayouts that I don't understand?

Comment: Problem probably isn't contained within the question. Tried a profiler, or even just `jstack` if it is taking so long? (And you do do everything Swing on the AWT EDT, right?)

Comment: Nope, the code I'm working from doesn't do any of the GUI updates from the EDT and I didn't even realize it.  I hate those "how did this ever work?" moments.  If you post this as an answer I'll accept it, I think you were ahead of the folks who posted the same thing as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling this code on the EDT.

Answer (score 3):

No it appears you understand GridLayouts.  The problem is elsewhere, look at other code that you might have changed, and do some profiling to determine the true source of the slowdown.